# Funcion con argumento arrays entero en C

Tags: funciones

Necesito que la funcion ImprimirArray( int array[], int size);
Pueda imprimir tambien con el nombre del array 
actualmente la funcion devuelve el nombre de cadena 
configurado en printf(); pero eso se mantiene constante con array[X]
Nosotros deseamos que si llamamos a la funcion 
Por ejemplo ImprimirArray( int precios[], 5);
Pueda imprimir con el prefijo precios[0], precios[1],

```
#include<stdio.h>

void ImprimirArray( int array[], int size); 
int main(){

int precios[5]={10,20,30,40,50};

ImprimirArray( precios, 5);
return 0;
}

void ImprimirArray( int array[], int size){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
        printf("array[%d]=%d\n",i,array[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta corta: **No puedes**.

C no tiene ningún tipo de información de introspección; no almacena ni el tamaño de tu *array*, mucho menos, el nombre usado para una variable.

Respuesta simple: ¿ Por qué no le pasas tú el nombre a la función ?

```
void ImprimirArray( const char *name, int array[], int size ) {
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        printf( "%s[%d] = %d\n", name, i, array[i] );
    }
}

...

ImprimirArray( "precios", precios, 5 );
```